# Unable to retain HIVE tables

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-spark

I have set up a single node hadoop cluster on ubuntu.I have installed hadoop 2.6 version on in my machine.

Problem:
Everytime i create HIVE tables and load data into it , i can see the data by querying on it but once i shut-down my hadoop , tables gets wiped out. Is there any way i can retain them or is there any setting i am missing?

I tried some online solution provided , but nothing worked , kindly help me out with this.

> *Blockquote*

Thanks
B

Answer (score 0):

The hive table data is on the hadoop hdfs, hive just add a `meta data` and provide users sql like commands to prevent them from writing basic MR jobs.So if you shutdown the hadoop cluster,Hive cant find the data in the table.

But if you are saying when you `restart` the hadoop cluster, the data is lost.That's another problem.

Answer (score 0):

seems you are using default derby as metastore.configure the hive metastore.i am pointing the link.please fallow it.
[Hive is not showing tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21227816/hive-is-not-showing-tables)