# Spark can access Hive table from pyspark but not from spark-submit

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

So, when running from pyspark i would type in (without specifying any contexts) :

```
df_openings_latest = sqlContext.sql('select * from experian_int_openings_latest_orc')
```

.. and it works fine.

However, when i run my script from `spark-submit`, like

`spark-submit script.py` i put the following in

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
conf = SparkConf().setAppName('inc_dd_openings')
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

df_openings_latest = sqlContext.sql('select * from experian_int_openings_latest_orc')
```

But it gives me an error

> pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u'Table not found:
>   experian_int_openings_latest_orc;'

So it doesnt see my table.

What am I doing wrong? Please help

P.S. Spark version is 1.6 running on Amazon EMR

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Spark 2.x**

The same problem may occur in Spark 2.x if `SparkSession` has been created without [enabling Hive support](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$Builder@enableHiveSupport():org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.Builder).

**Spark 1.x**

It is pretty simple. When you use PySpark shell, and Spark has been build with Hive support, default `SQLContext` implementation (the one available as a `sqlContext`) is `HiveContext`.

In your standalone application you use plain `SQLContext` which doesn't provide Hive capabilities.

Assuming the rest of the configuration is correct just replace:

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
```

with

```
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext

sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! :)

Answer (score 18):

In Spark 2.x (Amazon EMR 5+) you will run into this issue with `spark-submit` if you don't enable Hive support like this:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("yarn").appName("my app").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
```

Comment: Thanks, Mike I missed to add `enableHiveSupport` and was failing to run the required commands. By adding the property I am able to get the desired details.

Comment: This doesn't help with loading EMRFS jars though, right?  (e.g., `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem not found`)

Comment: works on Release label:emr-5.23.0 - Hadoop distribution:Amazon 2.8.5 - Applications:Hive 2.3.4, Pig 0.17.0, Hue 4.3.0, Spark 2.4.0, Zeppelin 0.8.1, Presto 0.215, Livy 0.5.0, thanks @Mike

Answer (score 2):

Your problem may be related to your `Hive` configurations. If your configurations use `local metastore`, the `metastore_db` directory gets created in the directory that you started you `Hive` server from.

Since `spark-submit` is launched from a different directory, it is creating a new `metastore_db` in that directory which does not contain information about your previous tables.

A quick fix would be to start the `Hive` server from the same directory as `spark-submit` and re-create your tables.

A more permanent fix is referenced in this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21227816/hive-is-not-showing-tables)

You need to change your configuration in `$HIVE_HOME/conf/hive-site.xml`

```
property name = javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL

property value = jdbc:derby:;databaseName=/home/youruser/hive_metadata/metastore_db;create=true
```

You should now be able to run hive from any location and still find your tables

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import getpass
username= getpass.getuser()
    
spark = SparkSession. \
builder. \
config("spark.ui.port","0"). \
config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir",f"/Users/{username}"/warehouse). \
enableHiveSupport(). \
appName(f'{username} | python- Processing Column Data'). \
master('yarn'). \
getOrCreate()
```

Comment: Could you explain us what your code does?