# How to query hdfs from a spark cluster (2.1) which is running on kubernetes?

Tags: python-3.x, kubernetes, pyspark

I was trying to access HDFS files from a spark cluster which is running inside Kubernetes containers.

However I keep on getting the error:
AnalysisException: 'The ORC data source must be used with Hive support enabled;'

What I am missing here?

Comment: Before Spark 2.3 (I think) there was no built-in library for ORC, Spark used the Hive libraries -- i.e. an _full_ install of the Hive client libraries, besides the Spark install, and the appropriate Classpath to reach these libs. Upgrade to V2.3 or 2.4 if you can...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you have SparkSession created with enableHiveSupport()?

Similar issue:
[Spark can access Hive table from pyspark but not from spark-submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36359812/spark-can-access-hive-table-from-pyspark-but-not-from-spark-submit)

Comment: Yes i have created a spark session with enableHiveSupport()
here is my code:

`conf = pyspark.SparkConf()
conf.setMaster("spark://10.41.0.5:7077"
conf.setAppName("test")

sc = pyspark.SparkContext(conf=conf)

spark = SparkSession(sc).builder.enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()


df = spark.read.orc("hdfs://....")`


and yet get the same error: AnalysisException: 'The ORC data source must be used with Hive support enabled;'`

Comment: Here hdfs is running on a separate cluster.