# Hadoop - Tables not displayed in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

The problem i am facing is: 
Everytime I login in to HIVE CLI, all the created databases & tables are gone. I can see them in the warehouse directory in Hadoop GUI. However same is not reflecting through CLI. Please help me resolve the issue.

I am using Hadoop - 1.0.4 & Hive - 1.2.1.
I have configured (warehouse dir, temp dir, derby metastore dir) inhive-site.xml as per documentation.

### properties in hive-site.xml

```
<property>
    <name>hive.exec.scratchdir</name>
    <value>/tmp/hive</value>
    <description>HDFS root scratch dir for Hive jobs which gets created with write all (733) permission. For each connecting user, an HDFS scratch dir: ${hive.exec.scratchdir}/&lt;username&gt; is created, with ${hive.scratch.dir.permission}.</description>
</property>

  <property>
    <name>hive.exec.local.scratchdir</name>
    <value>/tmp/hadoop/hive</value>
    <description>Local scratch space for Hive jobs</description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>hive.downloaded.resources.dir</name>
     <value>/tmp/hadoop/hive</value>
    <description>Temporary local directory for added resources in the remote file system.</description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>hive.scratch.dir.permission</name>
    <value>700</value>
    <description>The permission for the user specific scratch directories that get created.</description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>
    <value>/user/hive/warehouse</value>
    <description>location of default database for the warehouse</description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
    <value/>
    <description>Thrift URI for the remote metastore. Used by metastore client to connect to remote metastore.</description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>hive.metastore.connect.retries</name>
    <value>3</value>
    <description>Number of retries while opening a connection to metastore</description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
 <value>jdbc:derby:;databaseName=/usr/hadoop/metastore_db;create=true</value>
    <description>JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore</description>
  </property>
```

Comment: is table available in /user/hive/warehouse hdfs path?

Comment: Yes It is available. I stopped all hadoop components & restarted all fresh. also updated the metastore_db path. Now i can see the databases & tables reflecting on my new session as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21227816/hive-is-not-showing-tables

Comment: I had been through that thread. even afterhaving the same configurations, I was getting same exception. However after recycles, somehow the issue resolved.

Comment: after recycles?

Comment: I meant - restarting hadoop components. (stop-all.sh & then start-all.sh) :)